# Update internal model data of a filtered DelegateModel

Tags: qt, qml

I try to update data of a `DelegateModel` (or `VirtualDataModel`) in QML.

It seems that the data of the model which is passed to the `DelegateModel` is not triggered down to the "own" filtered model of `DelegateModel`.

So, how to update also the internal model of `DelegateModel`?

I try it with

```
visualDataModel.items.get(1).model.name = "clicked"
```

which seems to update the internal model. But this construct looks more like an hack...

**Working Example:**

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQml.Models 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.2
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2

Window {
    visible: true

    width: 400
    height: 400

    ListModel {
        id: listModel
        ListElement {
            name: "test1"
            key0: "1"
        }
        ListElement {
            name: "test2"
            key0: "1"
        }
        ListElement {
            name: "test3"
            key0: "0"
        }
        ListElement {
            name: "test4"
            key0: "0"
        }
    }

    ListView {
        id: listView
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.right: parent.right
        height: 200

        model: visualDataModel
    }

    Button {
        id: b
        anchors.top: listView.bottom
        text: "click me"

        onClicked: {
            listModel.get(1).name = "Clicked"
        }
    }

    DelegateModel {
        id: visualDataModel

        model: listModel

        groups: [
            VisualDataGroup {
                includeByDefault: false
                name: "key0"
            }

        ]

        filterOnGroup: "key0"

        delegate: Item {
            height: 50
            width: 50
            Text {
                text: name
            }
        }

        Component.onCompleted: {
            var rowCount = listModel.count;
            items.remove(0, rowCount);
            for(var i=0;i<rowCount;i++) {
                var entry = listModel.get(i);
                if(entry.key0 === "1") {
                    items.insert(entry, "key0");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make model data manimulation from delegate. I have changed your delegate like this:

```
delegate: Item {
    height: 50
    width: 50
    Text {
        id: txt
        anchors.top: parent.top
        text: name
    }
    Button {
        id: b
        anchors.top: txt.bottom
        text: "click me"

        onClicked: {
            name = "Clicked " + name
        }
    }
}
```

Also I have removed button from outside delegate.

Now every time I click button inside delegete data at model changes.

Comment: Well, but I want to change the model data from the outside of the delegate. The button was just a helper to show that the data is not updated when clicking.

Comment: Then you missunderstand MVC. I show you the right way for data manipulating. If you want change underling data directly then you can use this: `listModel.setProperty(0, "name", "Click")`. This works, but you should remove your strange code inside `Component.onCompleted` which kils all.

Comment: I am sorry, but you did not understand the "real" problem. I know how to manipulate data in a "normal" listmodel. But it seems that this does not work within a DelegateModel. Maybe you should check this before. Than you also understand the code in `onCompleted` function,

Answer (score 0):

items.insert will create new item.
so you should use items.setGroups, and the 3rd argument is a string array, which must contain "items"

Good luck!